# Bind an event of a slider control

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

In the view (`AudioView.xaml`) i have written the following code

```
<Slider
    Name="AudioSlider"
    Width="200"
    Height="23"
    Grid.Column="0"
    IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True"
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
    Maximum="{Binding Path=TotalAudioPlayingSeconds, Mode=OneTime}"
    Minimum="0"
    Style="{StaticResource CustomStyleForSlider}"
    Thumb.DragCompleted="{Binding AudioSliderChangedCommand}"
    TickFrequency="1"
    Value="{Binding Path=AudioPosition}"/>
```

Note: Also there is file `AudioView.xaml.cs`.

In the view model class(`AudioViewModel.cs`) i defined the following property

```
public event DragCompletedEventHandler AudioSliderChangedCommand;
```

and in the constructor of view model class (**AudioViewModel.cs**)

```
this.AudioSliderChangedCommand = new DragCompletedEventHandler(OnAudioSliderChanged);
```

During the compilation i am getting the following error

> Error 8   DragCompleted="{Binding AudioSliderChangedCommand}" is not
>   valid. {Binding AudioSliderChangedCommand} is not a valid event
>   handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or
>   code-behind class are valid.

Comment: Why is this labeled computer-science? I see nothing that is CS-theory-related in the question.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not in your code-behind, but in your XAML. Somewhere you do this:

```
DragCompleted="{Binding AudioSliderChangedCommand}"
```

This instructs the XAML deserializer to attach the `AudioSliderChangedCommand` handler to the `DragCompleted` event. However, `AudioSliderChangedCommand` is *not* a method with the appropriate signature (which can be attached as a handler) and it is *not* in your View class. And finally, you can't use `Binding` for event handlers.

To solve this, the simplest solution is to do this in your `View`:

```
private void DragCompletedEventHandler(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (YourViewModelType)this.DataContext;
    viewModel.OnAudioSliderChanged(this, e);
}
```

and also change

```
DragCompleted="{Binding AudioSliderChangedCommand}"
```

to

```
DragCompleted="DragCompletedEventHandler"
```

in your XAML.

This is how the above will work:

1. In your View, when `DragCompleted` is raised, the method `View.DragCompletedEventHandler` will be called
2. This method will get hold of the `AudioSliderChangedCommand` event (see note below) from the ViewModel and raise it, passing the original event args

**Important note**

You seem to be confused about events, event handlers and commands. Your code as it stands is  misleading. `AudioSliderChangedCommand` is an `event`, but the name suggests it's an `ICommand`. The appropriate name would be `AudioSliderChanged`.

Also, the appropriate MVVM way of doing this is by using some flavor of `DelegateCommand` (all decent MVVM frameworks have one; I used the class name for the implementation in Prism). Then, assuming that `AudioSliderChangedCommand` is indeed a command, the code-behind in your View would be:

```
private void DragCompletedEventHandler(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (YourViewModelType)this.DataContext;
    viewModel.AudioSliderChangedCommand.Execute();
}
```

It would also be possible to do without any code-behind at all by using some flavor of "event to command" attached behavior.

Comment: `The event AudioViewModel.AudioSliderChangedCommand' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type`

Comment: @Sreeju: That was an error in my code, sorry. Fixed it now. You will need to make the `OnAudioSliderChanged` method public.

Comment: The following code is written in AudioView.xaml.cs \n `private void DragCompletedEventHandler(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e) { var viewModel = (YourViewModelType)this.DataContext; viewModel.AudioSliderChangedCommand.Execute(); }`

Comment: We are using prism arch. Can you please suggest how i can do it using DelegateCommand

Comment: OnAudioSliderChanged is already public. The same error is comming :(

Comment: Thanks Jon for great help. Using the DelegateCommand and your code help me to solve the problem